# Update Table - Mysql

Tags: mysql

[image]

Need to update column c2 for all the values of same c3. i.e c3 has five 0's and top three 0's has 10 in c2. Here I need to update record 7 and 9 with value 10. At the end all 0's in c3 should have same c2 value i.e 10

Answer (score 1):

You need to take `self join` and then update the column `C2` as:

```
UPDATE table_name a
       INNER JOIN table_name b
           ON a.C2 = b.C3
SET a.C2 = b.C2
WHERE b.C2 <> 0;
```

Comment: sorry to say that its not about 0 is not a constant and like 0, there will be 1's 2's 3's etc

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to decide which record to take the value from for updating others?
`select c3 from yourTable group by c3` will return your distinct c3 values, now you can get corresponding c2 values fro each of c3, but how do you want to decide which value to use to update others?

Edit:
Few SQL statements approach:
`set @uniqueC3s = (select c3 from yourTable group by c3);

-- loop through the resutlset
set @requiredC2Value = (select TOP 1 c2 from yourTable where c3 = @uniqueC3s order by c1);

update yourTable set c2 = @requiredC2Value where c3 = @uniqueC3s;

-- end of loop`

Comment: In SQL there is no such thing as top most, there is 1st (in ordered result set), there are MAX(value) and MIN(value), there are other aggregate functions, but NO TOPMOST. In the unordered resultset you can NOT rely on the order of results as it may change over time as SQL server will try to optimise storage and in other cases.

Comment: It will still be 1st in RANDOM order...
Do you want it to be (order by c1)?

Comment: If you want it in one SQL statement it will have to be fairly complex, if few SQL statements are OK it will be more readable.